# DOM exception error 11 on swapCache()

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

I am playing with an application cache and having problems with the swapCache function.

I have created the world's simplest cache manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Timestamp: 2013-03-01 11:28:49

CACHE:
media/myImage.png

NETWORK:
*
```

Running the application for the 1st time gives me this in the console:

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest http://blah_blah/offline.appcache
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache Downloading event
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 1) http://blah_blah/media/myImage.png
Application Cache Progress event (1 of 1)
Application Cache Cached event
```

All well so far.  Then I swap out the image and change the timestamp in the manifest file and get the following:

```
Adding master entry to Application Cache with manifest http://blah_blah/offline.appcache
Application Cache Downloading event
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 2) http://blah_blah/media/myImage.png
Application Cache Progress event (1 of 2) http://blah_blah/Widget/?invoke=myWidgetFunctionName
Application Cache Progress event (2 of 2)
Application Cache UpdateReady event
```

At which point the applicationCache.swapCache() function is called giving me a DOM exception 11 error.

MIME types all correctly configured on the webserver.

Anyone got any ideas / can point me in the right direction?
(I have read all the commonly linked appcache stuff online and can't see what am I doing wrong)

Thanks!

EDIT:

As I mentioned in the comments below, setting the  expires headers on my web server for *.appcache files to expire immediately seems to have it working although I am still getting the DOM exception error(!?).  I found the following blog entry which may help:
[Possible Fix for Offline App Cache INVALIDSTATEERR](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/possible-fix-for-offline-app-cache-invalid_state_err)

...but I have no idea how to set the MIME types client side.  My google-Fu skillz have deserted me.  Anyone?

Comment: I am also getting this error occasionally/inconsistently and can't find the solution. Would love to hear if you figure it out.

Comment: I have now set the expires headers on my web server for *.appcache files to expire immediately and now the appcache seems to work as expected.  I am, however, still getting the DOM exception error 11 on the swapCache call so I'm not sure why it's working!

Comment: The link you posted simply suggests that you add the MIME types in your apache configuration (for me in `/etc/mime.types` by adding `text/cache-manifest   appcache`). I did that and checked the delivered mime type by using curl: `Content-Type: text/cache-manifest`. But I keep getting the same error whenever i call `appcache.update()` or `appcache.swapCache()`. I'd also love to hear someone figuring it out...

Comment: could you show us some code? It is possible that there is a bug calling swapCache twice, the page is somehow applying the update automatically, etc

Comment: @koko Did you ever get this to work? What did you do?

Comment: @DonRhummy Sorry, I don't remember the details, it's been quite a while. I remember putting this link in my code comments and I believe I found a solution once I fully understood the concept: http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For a while I just disabled the cache if the browser was not chrome, but then I decided to try again, setting the mime-type as suggested. Firefox no longer throws an exception when I call `swapCache()`, and the whole refreshing process now works as expected. The mime-type has to be set server-side since the request isn't initiated from your web page, but the browser, so you have no control over how it reads the response. You have a couple options here. If you are using apache or IIS, you can do as koko suggested. If you are using a framework that handles routing for you and you configure the mapping of URLs to responses, such as rails or a python wsgi server, then you can typically set the content type manually. Here is my snippet of what I am using in my Python app using Bottle.py (WSGI based):

```
# BEFORE
@bottle.route(r"/<path:re:.+\.(manifest|appcache)>", auth=False)
def serve_cache_manifest(path):
    return bottle.static_file(path, SITE_DIR)

# AFTER
@bottle.route(r"/<path:re:.+\.(manifest|appcache)>", auth=False)
def serve_cache_manifest(path):
    return bottle.static_file(path, SITE_DIR, mimetype='text/cache-manifest')
```

Bottle comes with a utility function that handles returning static files that I am using. It has an optional parameter to set the mime-type.

> **tl;dr** If you can't add the mime-type to your server configuration, you can almost always set it in your server side code (if you have
>   any).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to comment out the catchall NETWORK whitelist.

```
NETWORK:
# *
```

The * would seem to require network access for all file, according to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

I commented out all NETWORK entries for now for a simple web application of mine and it works well.